# Spinnaker on Titus cloud provider

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Are there any steps of configuring Spinnaker/Halyard to work on Titus based cluster? - https://netflix.github.io/titus/

There aren't any steps described in the documentation: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/

Also, check this Github issue: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.github.io/issues/869

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample config in the github repo:

`titus:
  enabled: true
  awsVpc: vpc0 # this is the default vpc used by titus
  accounts:
    - name: titusdevint
      environment: test 
      discovery: "http://discovery.compary.com/v2"
      discoveryEnabled: true
      registry: testregistry # reference to the docker registry being used
      awsAccount: test # aws account underpinning 
      autoscalingEnabled: true
      loadBalancingEnabled: false # load balancing will be released at a later date
      regions:
        - name: us-east-1
          url: https://myTitus.us-east-1.company.com/
          port: 7104 
          autoscalingEnabled: true
          loadBalancingEnabled: false 
        - name: eu-west-1
          url: https://myTitus.eu-west-1.company.com/
          port: 7104
          autoscalingEnabled: true
          loadBalancingEnabled: false`

https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/tree/master/clouddriver-titus

Right now you'll have to edit clouddriver.yml manually and then update via halyard